# Moving a Rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Ruby on Rails.

I need to copy a rails application to my own computer via git, which I have done.  I then tried `rails server` on the app, which threw a bunch of dependency complaints which I have fixed.

But now when I run `rails server`, the server exits and I receive the following error message:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:86:in `read': No such file or directory - /home/d/Desktop/ipr/urj/config/database.yml (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:86:in `database_configuration'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:58
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `run_load_hooks'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:1867
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/will_paginate-3.0.pre2/lib/will_paginate/finders/active_record.rb:31:in `enable!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/will_paginate-3.0.pre2/lib/will_paginate/railtie.rb:9
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
    from /home/d/Desktop/ipr/urj/config/environment.rb:5
    from /home/d/Desktop/ipr/urj/config.ru:3:in `require'
    from /home/d/Desktop/ipr/urj/config.ru:3
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
    from /home/d/Desktop/ipr/urj/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /home/d/Desktop/ipr/urj/config.ru:1
```

Must I copy the database somehow?

Answer (score 3):

run these commands:

```
bundle install
rake db:schema:load
rake db:test:prepare
```

Also, make sure that your `database.yml` file is included in the git repository. Sometimes, the default keeps this file in `.gitignore`, since different computers have different database configurations. If it doesn't exist, you might create a new app with `rails new test` and copy that `database.yml` file over. After that, you should be all set!

Comment: Do I run those commands on my end or the original server? I don't want to mess anything up!

Comment: Hey, run these over on your end, and all will be well.

Comment: I would run `rake db:schema:load` because that's the FINAL database schema, where as migrations will run every single little change.